# JIRA - Burn issues down on first SCRUM board then move to second DEPLOYMENT board

Tags: jira, agile, scrum, jira-agile, scrumboard

I'm trying to configure Jira to allow a development scrum team, then switch to deployment workflow. I want the issues to reach the done column on the development board, and the issue burn-down to count. I then want the issue to appear on a second board for testing. That board we drag the issues across into deployment.

How would I go about in doing this? I'm getting comfortable in the workflow screen and I don't have anything super complicated. I just want a burndown, then separate the the testing and deployment from development.

I also considered creating a new type of issue that is specifically used for testing and deployment. I would then add that new issue to the first column of the next board.

Any feedback will be very helpful.

Comment: Do you actually need need the issue to have a separate capital-W [Workflow](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AdminJIRAServer072/Working+with+workflows)? Or do you just mean that you want to walk the issue through a different set of transitions (which would still be within the same JIRA Workflow) but on a second board?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JIRA thinks of an issue as done if it has a resolution set (e.g. "fixed"). It doesn't matter if there are more statuses ahead in the workflow.

As an example, you could have the following workflow:

> To Do -> In Progress -> Done -> Ready for Release -> Released

Then you could add the resolution screen to the transition from In Progress to Done.

That way the issue transitions to Done and gets a resolution set. It counts against the burndown chart and would be shown as crossed out in the backlog view.

But you would still be able to carry on transitioning from Done to Ready for Release.

You can also use two boards and only map the statuses you want to see on the two boards.

For example, board 1:

> To Do, In Progress, Done

And board 2:

> Done, Ready for Release, Released

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have learned that story points are burnt down when the reach the right column on the board. I mapped all of the status on my second board to the last column on the first board... It works perfectly. Thank you again for your feedback.